# Side-nav list nested inside section accordion in Ember.js not displaying the items

Tags: ember.js, zurb-foundation

I am trying to use foundation UI with ember.js and I seem to have an issue with getting section to work properly. Anything within div class="content" doesn't appear. I am guessing this because of a href ='#' Section 1 . Where else could I be wrong? I don't have a clear understanding of how ember works as I am trying to figure things out.

```
            <div class="section-container accordion" data-section>
            <section class="section">
                <p class="title"><a href="#">Section 1</a></p>
                <div class="content">
                    <ul class="side-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Item !</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is due to the fact that by default, any element with `content` class inside a section is hidden. It will remain hidden unless you initialize foundation. The key to solving your issue is doing this:

```
$(document).foundation();
```

Now make sure you referenced Foundation's script: `foundation.min.js`

Comment: I made sure I included those script before i asked but it turns out the problem was with the python server I was running. I only needed to restart it. Anyways I switched to pure css accordion which gives me a lot of control in terms of what I want.